# SwiftUI Text with timer style gets truncated

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using `Text` with style `.timer` the time is truncated at certain times during the countdown. Setting `frame`, `fixedSize`, `layoutPriority`, `padding` didn't help. The following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(Date(), style: .timer)
    }
}
```

will display: `O:00`, `O:01`, `O:02`, `O:03`,`O:...` (gets truncated), `O:05` etc.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

There are similar question like this, but they didn't help:

[Text inside a VStack truncates when it's not supposed to in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811179/text-inside-a-vstack-truncates-when-its-not-supposed-to-in-swiftui)

[SwiftUI Text Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375064/swiftui-text-behavior)

Comment: I've run into this problem in my own project and found no proper solution.  Even if you do `Text(date, style: .timer).frame(minWidth: 200).background(Color.green)` you can see that the view is plenty wide but the text is still truncated as the timer counts up.  It seems reasonable to assume it's a bug in Apple's beta code.  I've filed a bug in Feedback Assistant and I encourage you to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with monospaced style. Tested with Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14.

```
Text(Date(), style: .timer)
   .font(Font.system(size: 16).monospacedDigit())
```

Comment: This will fail after ten minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately  @JamieA is still right, even today with the released OS :-(

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Apple's code, which has since been fixed.  When building with Xcode 12 beta 6 / running on iOS 14 beta 6, the timer will not truncate.

Comment: Still not fixed in the release. Have to make font size decision on my own.
Määäähhhh